# JQuery .load() Images not displaying

Tags: jquery, html

Using jquery .load() method to load an html file into a div. The page does load; however the images do not display (even though they show in the network activity in the developer console.)  If I reload the entire site, the images will show.  Clearing the cache; however, results in the images not showing again until I reload.  My HTML:

```
<div id="aboutus">
   <h2>About us</h2>
   <div class="biocard">
      <img src="/resources/person1.png" alt="Person 1 Image">
      <div class="biotext">
         <h2>Meet Persion 1</h2>
         <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="biocard">
      <img src="/resources/person2.png" alt="Person 2 Image">
      <div class="biotext">
         <h2>Meet Persion 2</h2>
         <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="biocard">
      <img src="/resources/person3.png" alt="Person 3 Image">
      <div class="biotext">
         <h2>Meet Persion 3</h2>
         <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
      .biocard{
        display: flex;
        border-top: 1px solid $base-color;
        align-items: center;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        h2{
          color: $base-color;
        }
        img{
          border-radius: 50%;
          width: 200px;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0px 15px 10px 0px;
        }
}
```

JQuery:

```
$("#pagecontent").load("/documents/aboutus.html");
```

`pagecontent` is a simple div I have residing on the currently loaded page.

*** EDIT ***

It looks like removing the `img{height: 100%;}` in the css fixed the problem. Wondering if the div.biocard height is not known at the time of the load and the image heights are set to 0.

Comment: $(function () { $("#pagecontent").load("/documents/aboutus.html"); }) does this work?

Comment: I'm afraid it does not.  After clearing the cache and loading the page the images still do not display.

Comment: better set height to auto if you set width.